# Fargo S1 main character connected to the movie?

Tags: fargo-tv, fargo

Is there a connection between the character, Molly Solverson and any other character of the Fargo movie?
I wonder if there is a connection between Marge Gunderson and Molly Solverson, like heritage or something.

Comment: They are only connected out of universe - Molly is somewhat based on Marge. Whole 1st season is somewhat based on the movie. It's not a remake, but some characters are analogous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Molly is not related to any character from the feature film but her dad, Lou Solverson, does connect with season 2's story that takes place earlier in the 1970s.

The only firm [connection](https://www.bustle.com/articles/27483-fargo-the-tv-show-is-connected-to-fargo-the-film-but-how) season 1 makes to the feature film, is how Stavros Milos (Oliver Platt's character) came up with the money to start his business, which was left behind by Carl Showalter (Steve Buscemi's character) from the events of the *Fargo* feature film.

> "In a flashback, we learned that Stavros happened upon a suitcase full
> of money buried in the snow on the side of the road after his car
> broke down. He made the lucky find after glimpsing a red ice scraper
> stuck in the snow by a nondescript fence. Stavros took the money for
> himself and used it to start his company (which takes us up to the
> "present day" of the show: 2006)."

Comment: the thing is that this Molly character is so similar to Marge, clever, suspects about everything and makes intelligent connections and seems to have a great empathy as well, that must be something inherited, by the writter I guess.

Comment: @DanielV while I see what you are getting at and while that would make for a good theory, at this point it's "thematic", meaning that when Hawley took over the IP, he wanted to make sure some things were consistent to what the Coen Brothers have done in order to make it what he sees as 'Frago'. Marge and Molly are "similar" cop protagonists or Fargo archtypes. Season 2 for instance, also winks at No Country for Old Men and The Man who Wasn't There and makes a couple of connections to season 1. There is just no in-universe evidence to prove they are related so they are just thematically similar

Comment: yes, I see, it's just like Tarantino's universe